# Button only works every other time in Flash

Tags: flash, button, actionscript, adobe

The "look around" button in my Flash project only works every other time you click it. All of my other buttons have the same code and work fine. Here's my ActionScript code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

escape_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressedEscape)
function pressedEscape(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    animations.gotoAndPlay("escape");
}

bio_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressedBio);
function pressedBio(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("biography");
}

home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressedHome);
function pressedHome(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("home");
}

analysis_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressedAnalysis);
function pressedAnalysis(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("analysis");
}

lookaround_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressedLookAround)
function pressedLookAround(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    animations.gotoAndPlay("look around");
}


stop();
```

here are some screen captures of my animation timeline:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what you have posted looks fine. presumably problem somewhere in animations

Comment: I added screen captures from my timeline, hopefully that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in actions on same frame as "look around" label.

Im guessing there is a stop() command there; ive found when using gotoAndPlay, it can be buggy if you also have a stop() at the frame that gotoAndPlay is jumping to. Flash gets confused becausse it has been told to play but also to stop.

Comment: You were right about the stop() being in the same frame as the "look around" label. I added in a keyframe before the "look around" label and put the stop() command there instead. Thanks!